# Proof of the Homotopy Lemma in Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, proof-verification, differential-topology

> **Homotopy Lemma** Let $f, g : M \to N$ be smoothly homotopic maps between manifolds of the same dimension, where $M$ is compact and without boundary. If $y \in N$ is a regular value for both $f$ and $g$, then $$\#f^{-1}(y) = \#g^{-1}(y) \ \ \ \ \  (\text{mod}\  2)$$

Now in his proof there's a line that says the following,

> But we recall from Chapter $2$, that a compact $1$-manifold always has an even number of boundary points.

I don't see why this is true, the circle $\mathbb{S}^1$ is a compact $1$-manifold, and it seems to have infinitely many boundary points.

Futhermore, the result that Milnor seems to be quoting, is the classification of $1$-manifolds in the appendix of *Topology from the Differentiable Viewpoint*. However that result requires, $M$ to be connected, however that is not one of the required conditions on the Homotopy Lemma.

Is this an error in the book? (Also I'm not sure that Chapter $2$ contains the result that Milnor is quoting).

Comment: No, there is no error. Each circle has no boundary and each straight-line segment has $2$ boundary points. In general, I don't think there are errors in this book by now.

Comment: Do you know the definition of a "manifold-with-boundary"? And do you know the definition of the "boundary of a manifold-with-boundary"? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Manifold_with_boundary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boundary of a manifold with boundary is different from the topological boundary. This is a crucial point. A circle is a manifold without boundary, hence has $0$ boundary points.

The classification of $1$-manifolds tells you that a connected, compact $1$-dimensional manifold with boundary is either a closed interval or a circle. This then tells you what the components of a general compact $1$-dimensional manifold with boundary must be.

Comment: Okay I think you are using the fact that manifolds (with or without boundary) are locally connected.  So let $M$ be a compact $1$-dimensional manifold with boundary, every component of $M$ is closed, and hence compact, furthermore every component of $M$ is open so we have the components of $M$ to be compact $1$-manifolds, but I don't see why those components need to have boundaries. But even if the components do have boundaries (in which case we can use the classification of $1$-manifolds), I still don't see why we conclude that $M$ always has an even number of boundary points.

Comment: Any component that is a circle has $0$ boundary points. $0$, last time I checked, is an even number. (I already said this!)

Comment: I get that, but if the components of $M$ always have an even number of boundary points, how do we know $M$ has an even number of boundary points? That's what I'm trying to ask

Comment: Um, what's the sum of a finite number of even numbers? I really don't get what your issue is.

Comment: My issue was the following. If $\{C_i\}_{i \in I}$ were the components of $M$, each component has $2$ boundary points or $0$ boundary points, how do we know that the number of boundary points of $M$ is $\sum_{i \in [1, ..., n]} \#\text{Bd}(C_i)$ where $\#\text{Bd}(C_i)$ is the number of boundary points of each component. What I'm trying to ask is how can we add all of the boundary points of the components of $M$ to get all of the boundary points of $M$?

Comment: I still cannot imagine what you're missing. Any boundary point—indeed, any point—of $M$ must be in some component. The transversality conditions insure that the only boundary points can occur at the boundary of $M\times I$ and that every point that sits in $M\times \partial I$ is a boundary point of our $1$-dimensional manifold with boundary. (We shouldn't have been using $M$ for the compact $1$-dimensional manifold with boundary. Everything is inside $M\times I$.)

Comment: "The transversality conditions insure that the only boundary points can occur at the boundary of $M \times I$".... Ah so the only boundary points for components of $M \times I$ can occur at $\partial(M \times I) = M \times \partial I$? Is that by transversality (as in Chapter 1.5 of G&P?). If so I wasn't aware of that result as I haven't reached that chapter in G&P yet.

Comment: Again, we're having notational confusion. I'm going to switch letters. Suppose $f\colon X\to Y$, where $X$ is a compact manifold with boundary and $Y$ is a manifold. Suppose $Z$ is a closed submanifold of $Y$. If $f,\partial f\pitchfork Z$, then $f^{-1}(Z)\subset X$ is a compact submanifold with boundary, and the boundary is precisely $f^{-1}(Z) \cap\partial X$. Note that Milnor says this (in the case at hand) on the top of p. 22.

Comment: Oh, in fact, see Lemma 4 on p. 13 of Milnor. This is precisely what he addresses there.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**: Full credit for this answer must go to Prof. Ted Shifrin (above). This is just a small expansion on his answer for sake of completeness (and so that I don't forget).

---

In the appendix of Milnor, it's stated that any smooth, connected $1$-dimensional manifold is diffeomorphic to either the circle $S^1$, or to some interval of real numbers.

One can easily see from this that any smooth, connected, compact, $1$-manifold is diffeomorphic to $[0, 1]$ or $S^1$ (because these are the only compact options that a smooth, connected $1$-manifold can be diffeomorphic to).

Now suppose $M$ was a smooth, compact, *but not necessarily connected*, $1$-manifold, since every manifold is locally connected, the components of $M$ are open in $M$ and hence also $1$-manifolds, and in any topological space the components of the space are closed, hence the components of $M$ are compact, and they are connected (by the definition of a component), hence they are diffeomorphic either to $[0, 1]$ or $S^1$.

Each component $C \subseteq M$ can easily be seen to have either two boundary points, $\{0, 1\}$ if $C$ is diffeomorphic to $[0, 1]$, or zero boundary points if $C$ is diffeomorphic to $S^1$. Summing all of those boundary points up we get the number of boundary points of $M$, which is thus even.

The fact that adding up all the boundary points of the components of $M$ yields the total number of boundary points in $M$ is intuitive. Take $\left[0, \frac{1}{2}\right] \cup \left[1, 2\right]$, which is a smooth, compact, disconnected $1$-manifold as a prototypical example.